# Why Custom Build Step works in VS2012 but doesn't work in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, cmake

I noticed that `Custom Build Steps` stopped working in my Visual Studio 2013. e.g. CMAKE generated ZERO_CHECK doesn't work. I tried everything from [Troubleshooting Build Customizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0bktkzs.aspx) but nothing helped.

---

I created simple c++ console application, changed Item Type for ReadMe.txt from `text` to `Custom Build Tool`, and entered simple commands to `Command Line`.

```
@echo on
copy %0 test.bat
del c:\1.txt
```

In project file it looks like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <CustomBuild Include="ReadMe.txt">
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">@echo on
copy %0 test.bat
del c:\1.txt</Command>
    </CustomBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
```

In Visual Studio 2012 everything work as supposed, file test.bat created, file c:\1.txt deleted. But in Visual Studio 2013 it doesn't work.
Visual Studio 2013 output:

```
1>Target "ComputeCustomBuildOutput: (TargetId:28)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets" from project "D:\Projects\Projects\VS2013Test\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012.vcxproj" (target "CustomBuild" depends on it):
1>Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(CustomBuildDirsToMake.OutputFileToTool)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
1>Task "MakeDir" (TaskId:15)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      Directories=
1>          D:\Projects\Projects\VS2013Test\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012\
1>                  AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes=
1>                  Command=@echo on
1>  copy %0 test.bat
1>  del c:\1.txt
1>                  LinkObjects=true
1>                  Message=Performing Custom Build Tools
1>                  MinimalRebuildFromTracking=true
1>                  Outputs=SomeText;
1>                  TrackerLogDirectory=Debug\CppConsole2012.tlog\
1>                  TreatOutputAsContent=false (TaskId:15)
1>Done executing task "MakeDir". (TaskId:15)
1>Done building target "ComputeCustomBuildOutput" in project "CppConsole2012.vcxproj".: (TargetId:28)
1>Target "CustomBuild: (TargetId:29)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets" from project "D:\Projects\Projects\VS2013Test\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012.vcxproj" (target "_BuildGenerateSourcesAction" depends on it):
1>Done building target "CustomBuild" in project "CppConsole2012.vcxproj".: (TargetId:29)
```

Visual Studio 2012 Output:

```
1>Target "ComputeCustomBuildOutput: (TargetId:41)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets" from project "D:\Projects\Projects\VS2012Test\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012.vcxproj" (target "CustomBuild" depends on it):
1>Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(CustomBuildDirsToMake.OutputFileToTool)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
1>Task "MakeDir" (TaskId:27)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      Directories=
1>          D:\Projects\Projects\VS2012Test\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012\
1>                  AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes=
1>                  Command=@echo on
1>  copy %0 test.bat
1>  del c:\1.txt
1>                  LinkObjects=true
1>                  Message=Performing Custom Build Tools
1>                  MinimalRebuildFromTracking=true
1>                  Outputs=SomeText;
1>                  TrackerLogDirectory=Debug\
1>                  TreatOutputAsContent=false (TaskId:27)
1>Done executing task "MakeDir". (TaskId:27)
1>Done building target "ComputeCustomBuildOutput" in project "CppConsole2012.vcxproj".: (TargetId:41)
1>Target "CustomBuild: (TargetId:42)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets" from project "D:\Projects\Projects\VS2012Test\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012.vcxproj" (target "_BuildGenerateSourcesAction" depends on it):
1>Using "CustomBuild" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.v110, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "CustomBuild" (TaskId:28)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      Sources=
1>          ReadMe.txt
1>                  AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes=
1>                  Command=@echo on
1>  copy %0 test.bat
1>  del c:\1.txt
1>                  LinkObjects=true
1>                  Message=Performing Custom Build Tools
1>                  MinimalRebuildFromTracking=true
1>                  Outputs=SomeText;
1>                  TrackerLogDirectory=Debug\
1>                  TreatOutputAsContent=false (TaskId:28)
1>  Task Parameter:BuildSuffix=
1>  :VCEnd (TaskId:28)
1>  Task Parameter:TrackerLogDirectory=Debug\ (TaskId:28)
1>  Task Parameter:MinimalRebuildFromTracking=True (TaskId:28)
1>  Task Parameter:TrackFileAccess=True (TaskId:28)
1>  Task Parameter:ToolArchitecture=Native32Bit (TaskId:28)
1>  Forcing rebuild of all source files due to missing command TLog "D:\Projects\Projects\VS2012Test\CppConsole2012\CppConsole2012\Debug\custombuild.command.1.tlog". (TaskId:28)
1>  @echo on
1>  copy %0 test.bat
1>  del c:\1.txt (TaskId:28)
1>  Performing Custom Build Tools (TaskId:28)
1>          1 file(s) copied. (TaskId:28)
1>  Could Not Find c:\1.txt (TaskId:28)
1>Done executing task "CustomBuild". (TaskId:28)
1>Done building target "CustomBuild" in project "CppConsole2012.vcxproj".: (TargetId:42)
```

You can see part of VS2012 log is absent in VS2013:

```
1>Using "CustomBuild" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.v110, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "CustomBuild" (TaskId:28)
...
1>Done executing task "CustomBuild". (TaskId:28)
```

Comment: Which version of CMake do you have?

Comment: I have CMAKE version 3.2.1

Comment: I only can say that uninstall and install again Visual Studio 2013 helped me. (repair didn't help). Now the issue is fixed.

Comment: In this case, you should preferably post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `Outputs` metadata. See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy.aspx) for info.

```
<ItemGroup>
<CustomBuild Include="ReadMe.txt">
    <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
@echo on
copy %0 test.bat
del c:\1.txt
    </Command>
    <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">test.bat;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
</CustomBuild>
</ItemGroup>
```

Without it, I get a warning from the `CustomBuild` task,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): warning MSB8018: No outputs specified for item "ReadMe.txt". Its custom build command will be skipped. [<PATH>\SandboxCpp.vcxproj]
  @echo on
          copy %0 test.bat
          del c:\1.txt (TaskId:15)
Done executing task "CustomBuild". (TaskId:15)
```

I'm guessing you didn't get the printout of `Using "CustomBuild" task from assembly` because your verbosity level is too low in the VS2013 log (there should be a lot more there).